# AngulareJS e2e check each link in a list

Tags: javascript, element, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'll be using the e2e part mostly (with jasmine). After literally a few days of getting nowhere with this (I'm finding the documentation pretty anorexic to say the least!) I'm wondering if someone could help me here:

A website generates an html list of a=href links. I can 'click' on a link using angularjs e2e like this:

```
element('li a').click();
```

Fine. But here's two questions:

1. If there are 6 links in the list, which link is this clicking?? (in the html code that's being tested, these links have no unique id and some could be exactly the same reference / url etc..)?
2. How can I loop through each link in the list? i.e. element(links[1]).click() -> ... do whatever then navigate back -> element(links[2]).click() -> ... do whatever then navigate back ... etc...

(NOTE: angularjs e2e's version of 'element' is not the same as 'angular.element'.)

Comment: what do you get when you do a console.log on 'element('li a')'

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED!!!**

```
element('li:eq(0) a').click(); //<-- clicks the first link.

element('li:eq(1) a').click(); //<-- clicks the 2nd link.
```

etc...

A developer here showed me this, but I've no idea how he knew!

Answer (score 2):

Okay - in case anyone else is curious (I can't be the only person on earth trying to figure this stuff out!) I've worked question 1 out for myself: By hard-coding values into a list I found that

```
element('li a')
```

... will select the *last* listed item.

---

So, on with the seemingly unsolvable issue of making 'element()' select a specific item in a list.

```
console.log("ROYDEBUG: " + element('li a'));
```

... returns "ROYDEBUG: [object Object]" to the console log.

**BUT** I can get it to recognise that there are 'x' list items. If I do this:

```
   element('li a').query(function (selectedElements, done) {
        selectedElements.each(function(idx,elm)
            {
                var thisOne = selectedElements[idx]; //<-- (same as "= this;").
                console.log("ROYDEBUG:  " + idx + " - " + thisOne);
                //element(thisOne).click();                //<-- doesn't work :(
                //element(this).click();                   //<-- doesn't work :(
                //element(selectedElements[idx]).click();  //<-- doesn't work :(
            });
        done();
   });
```

Then I get this in the console:

```
ROYDEBUG: [object Object]
ROYDEBUG:  0 - http://localhost:9876/app/index.html#/coupon/100
ROYDEBUG:  1 - http://localhost:9876/app/index.html#/coupon/100
ROYDEBUG:  2 - http://localhost:9876/app/index.html#/coupon/100
ROYDEBUG:  3 - http://localhost:9876/app/index.html#/coupon/100
ROYDEBUG:  4 - http://localhost:9876/app/index.html#/coupon/100
ROYDEBUG:  5 - http://localhost:9876/app/index.html#/coupon/100
```

... so it *knows* there are 6 items in the list. However I can't use "element().click()" to these returned 'elements' because they're just the text string from the 'href=' part of each link (as you can see in the console output above).