# How does the "element(selector, label).query(fn)" method work in Angular E2E tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, bdd, acceptance-testing

When writing E2E tests for **Angular Scenario Runner** I came across a `query()` method:

```
element(selector, label).query(fn)
```

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) says:

> Executes the function fn(selectedElements, done), where selectedElements are the elements that match the given jQuery selector and done is a function that is called at the end of the fn function. The label is used for test output.

So I wrote an it-case for a set of buttons on my html-page:

```
it('should display all buttons on page load', function () {
    var buttonText = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
    element('button', 'UI elements').query(function (selectedElements, done) {
        selectedElements.each(function (idx, elm) {
            expect(elm.innerText in buttonText).toEqual(true);
        });
        done();
    });
});
```

As a result of test execution I received a list of 10 failed expect-clauses with text:

> expected true but was undefined

Intermediate debugging showed that `elm.innerText in buttonText` condition is truthy.

So my question is, what went wrong? Is it the incorrect usage of `done()` method?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you should be doing `elm.text()`, not `elm.innerText`, as you would get back angular-wrapped elements and not raw ones.

Comment: @AndyJoslin I thought so too, but it is wrong. I receive `TypeError: Object [object HTMLButtonElement] has no method 'text'` error in case of using the `.text()` method.

Comment: Try adding some `dump(elm.innerText)` and check and see what comes out.

Comment: @AndyJoslin I get only one error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` when using `dump()`...

Comment: @JohnDoe try another type of `expect` for `elm`, for example `elm.nodeType`. Do you use jQuery? Note: for `toEqual(true)` there is `toBeTruthly()` method.

Comment: Take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473545/2037203) to the "[AngulareJS e2e check each link in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442386/angularejs-e2e-check-each-link-in-a-list)" question.

Answer (score 2):

You can not call expect() inside the element().query() function.

But you can do the following

```
var promise = element('SELECTOR').query(function(selectedElements, done) {
    // We are in JQuery land.
    if (selectedElements < 1) {
      done('ERROR MESSAGE')
    } else {
      done(null, selectedElements[0].innerText)
    }
    // For documentation only.
    // Don't return anything... just continue.
    done()
})
expect(promise).toEqual('i am waiting for you')
```

You can combine promise and expect into a single call.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct except for the 'expect' line:

```
expect(elm.innerText in buttonText).toEqual(true);
```

The parameter to 'expect' is a future.
From the documentation, since *All API statements return a future object*, `elm.innerText` returns a future,
but `elm.innerText in buttonText` does not, resulting in undefined.
Perhaps, the way to code this would be:

```
expect(elm.innerText).toMatch(/\d/);
```